# How to connect to kubernetes cluster locally and open dashboard?

Tags: shell, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a new laptop and kubernetes cluster running on Google Cloud Platform. How can I access that cluster from local machine to execute kubectl commands, open dashboard etc?

That is not clearly stated in the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

From your local workstation, you need to have the `gcloud` tool installed and properly configured to connect to the correct GCE account. Then you can run:

```
 gcloud container clusters get-credentials [CLUSTER_NAME]
```

This will setup `kubectl` to connect to your kubernetes cluster.

Of course you'll need to install kubectl either using gcloud with:

```
gcloud components install kubectl
```

Or using specific instructions for your operating system.

Please check the following link for more details: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/quickstart

Once you have kubectl access you can deploy and access the kubernetes dashboard as described here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/web-ui-dashboard/

Comment: Thank you for the answer! What if I will use i.e. Digital Ocean and setup cluster on my own outside of GCE?

Comment: Tipically, k8s clusters use certificates to authenticate calls to the API server. If you are on premises you need to generate a user certificate on the master node and copy the public key in your workstation.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you would need to do once you've installed Cloud SDK is ensure it is authenticated to your Google Cloud Platform account/project. To do this you need to run:

```
gcloud auth login
```

And then follow the on screen instructions.

Also you will need to install kubectl to access/control aspests of your cluster:

```
gcloud components install kubectl
```

You can also install it through native package management by following the instructions [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl/#install-kubectl-binary-via-native-package-management).

Once your gcloud is authenticated to your project you can run this to ensure kubectl is pointing at your cluster and authenticated:

```
gcloud container clusters get-credentials CLUSTER_NAME --zone ZONE
```

You'll now be able to issue commands with kubectl that target the cluster you defined in the previous step.

You can access the dashboard following the instructions [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/web-ui-dashboard/).